# Multiple numpy arrays (index, data) fastest way to Spark Dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to create a **Spark Dataframe** directly from multiple **data and timestamp index Numpy arrays** (Time series data)

I have one master array that contains all unique indices of all data arrays. 
The sample datatypes are double, long, int or string in Spark Dataframe.

Each data array should be a new column in Spark Dataframe.

Example data:

```
idx1:  [2.00e-01, 3.00e-01, 4.00e-01, ... 5.00e+03, 6.00e+03]
data1: [ 0,  10,   15, ... 65535, 65535, 65535]
...
idx2: [8.70e-01, 5.70e+02, ... 9.90e+02, 1.07+03 1.12e+03]
data2: [19282, 19282, 19282, ... 19284, 19285, 19286]

masterIndex: [2.00e-01, 3.00e-01, 4.00e-01, 8.70e-01, 5.70e+02, ...]
```

Goal Spark Dataframe (autofill NaN):

```
| masterIdx| data1 |data(N)| ... |
|     0.2  |   0   |  NaN  | ... |
| ...      |    .. |  ..   | ... |
|     0.87 |  NaN  | 19282 | ... |
```

In my current approach I do the following steps:

1. Create empty Panda Dataframe with masterIndex as index
2. Numpy arrays index and samples as Panda Series
3. Merge Panda Series as column on Panda Dataframe -> `df[name] = pdSeries`
4. Convert Panda Dataframe to Spark Dataframe with Pyarrow enabled and Schema for data types

How can I **add / merge multiple numpy data arrays** as columns (with index array) **efficiently to a Spark Dataframe**?
I would like to directly write the data into the Spark Dataframe.

The goal is to have the **best performance creating the Spark Dataframe**.

Thank you - for your input!